# Generating reports, such as income/loss etc

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have 2 tables, purchases and sales with each having a date field and a cost field.

I want to generate reports of a few different types, for example I want to show profit and loss over each month or year, or to show how often a particular item sold for a given arbitrary time period ( probably based on user input)

Is it terribly complex to do queries such as this, do they rely on complex calculations?

For example, how would I total the sales.costs field and the total of purchases.costs to show profit and loss?

Comment: Are you looking for a (mostly) pure SQL solution?

Comment: That's a good question.  It seems implied, but sometimes people are happy with other solutions, which might be easier to maintain if the devs aren't familiar with advanced SQL.

Comment: @Benson Precisely.  With my background in ad-hoc reporting, my first thought was: use Crystal Reports.  You can do some rather complicated things with SQL, but you must ask if it's worth the complexity. This appears to have complication written all over it.  How are the tables going to be joined (and then rolled up)? If it's complex enough, it may be more efficient to split things between the DB and something else (or temp tables). I once re-did a query which brought an AS/400 server to it's knees, in 30 minutes. But, it required several steps and data massaging in order to avoid insane joins.

Comment: @George Yeah, you can do some cool stuff in SQL but you have to be very careful if you're running them on a production server. Still, if this is part of a webapp (which wouldn't surprise me), there's a good chance building it in as part of the existing UI would be super handy. I'm building a custom reporting tool in a webapp right now, incidentally. :-)

Comment: @Benson LOL, how ironic.  The fact that this may be for a webapp is the reason I didn't suggest Crystal Reports or some other report creation software.  Now, depending on the specifics, it could make more sense to do some of the data roll-up in PHP (or whatever), in order to avoid overley complex/fragile SQL.

Comment: Agreed, but it can also be cheaper to do a lot of it in SQL, depending on the sorts of data you're dealing with.  It's very dependent on the db schema and quantities of data you have to deal with.

Comment: I am working with phpBMS, which is a type of CMS like system. The built in reports facilit ycan not do what I want, so as far as I know I have to do it all in SQL

Comment: @Jacob You should still be able to do things in PHP, if need be, but I'm not that familiar with phpBMS.  In your situation, I would probably try to do it with SQL.  Should that prove to be too complicated/fragile/resource-intensive then look for ways simply things.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is fairly straight forward, and an excellent example of why SQL databases are powerful and fun to use.  For your example query, I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(purchases.costs) + SUM(sales.costs) AS total_cost FROM purchases, sales;
```

To do a query that gives you cost by year, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(sales.cost) + SUM(purchases.cost) AS cost,
       YEAR(sales.ts) AS year 
  FROM sales INNER JOIN purchases 
       ON YEAR(sales.ts) = YEAR(purchases.ts)
  GROUP BY YEAR(sales.ts);
```

Comment: is YEAR an inbuilt function that works on date fields? For example would MONTH work in place of year?

Comment: @Jacob Yup, check out the Date & Time functions in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html  Make sure it's the appropriate section for your version of MySQL. (Look on the left side of the page.) That is for version 5.1.